# convert variable to type of another variable in a lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

If I have the following variables:

```
x = 100.0
y = "100.0"
```

I am wanting to convert `y` into whatever the type of `x` is, but am trying to do so via a lambda.

Comment: What is the overall purpose of this task?

Comment: What would you want to happen if `x = 100` and `y = '1.5'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there exists a instance creator for type `x` which takes a single argument of type `y` and does the right thing, you could just call `type(x)(y)`:

```
>>> x = 100.0
>>> y = "100.0"
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(x)(y)
100.0
```

This works for the example given in the OP, but will yield subtle or errors or outright failures in other cases.

But "via a lambda" doesn't make much sense.  A lambda is just a certain, not-very-powerful syntax to define an anonymous function.  It's not a special kind of function.  You can write

```
>>> def f(x,y): return type(x)(y)
>>> f(100.0, "200.0")
200.0
```

If you really insisted, you could write

```
>>> f = lambda x,y: type(x)(y)
>>> f(100.0, "200.0")
200.0
```

but this will make most Python programmers wonder if you're new to Python, because there's no reason to use a lambda to define an anonymous function and then immediately give it a name.

Comment: This works for the explicit OP case because there just happens to be a one argument instance creation method of float that happens to take a string and interpret it as a float. Outside of some very narrow cases like this one, this approach is highly likely to not work, a simple example would be `x = []; y = '100.00'`.

Comment: @msw: well, yes.  Only coercions which are natively supported by the target type work; anything else would be guessing in the face of ambiguity, and that's a temptation we're officially supposed to refuse.